# Get all users who haven't logged into box.com for more than 60 days

Tags: box-api, box

I need to get all details of users who haven't performed any activity or login into box.com account for more than 60 days. Is there any API or way to do it?

Comment: Please add what ever you tried for this.

Comment: I am trying to do it through https://api.box.com/2.0/users
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" , but its not returning last activity performed date by user. I am still finding a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are an administrator for your Box enterprise, this is possible with the API. However, you have to do it in three steps, and it will require a bit of client-side work.

**1.** 
First [get a list of all enterprise users](https://developers.box.com/docs/#users-get-all-the-users-in-an-enterprise) as you're already doing now:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Depending on the number of users in your enterprise, you will need to repeat this call with an increasing `offset` parameter to get all of them. See the docs for more detail.

**2.** 
Then [get a list of all enterprise events](https://developers.box.com/docs/#events-get-events-in-an-enterprise) that occurred within the last 60 days:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/events?stream_type=admin_logs
                                   &created_after=2014-05-07T00:00:00-08:00 
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

As with the user list, this events list could potentially be quite long. You will likely need to repeat that call multiple times with an increasing `stream_position`. Again, the docs explain this in greater detail.

**3.**
At this point you have a list of enterprise [User](https://developers.box.com/docs/#users-user-object) objects and a list of enterprise [Event](https://developers.box.com/docs/#events-event-object) objects. The Event object has a property `created_by` that corresponds to the user that performed the action. A distinct set of `created_by.id` values will provide you with the ID of every user that was active in the last N days -- we'll call this list `active_user_ids`. You can then filter the User objects for any ID that does *not* appear in this list. Those are your inactive users. As pseudo code:

```
foreach user in users
  if active_user_ids does not contain user.id
     print "user.name has been not been active for at least 60 days"
  else
     print "user.name has been active within the last 60 days"
```

**Note:** Depending on the number and activity of users in your enterprise, the Events list will take a significant amount of time to gather. Consider using the `event_type` query string parameter to limit the types of events to just those that you're really interested in.

Comment: Thanks John , it was quite explanatory. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In step 2 of the above solution - I believe there is a way to retrieve only the LOGIN events.  Otherwise the list of events can be pretty large!

Comment: I recommend adding this as a comment.